# Angular UI map, info window is not open

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using angular UI-map module
The marker is added on the map but when I click it, it shows

```
Cannot call method 'open' of undefined
```

and I tried to just call alert and it work. Any idea?

In html

```
            <div    ng-repeat="marker in meMarker"
                    ui-map-marker="meMarker[$index]" 
                    ui-event="{'map-click': 'showMarkerInfo(marker)'}">
            </div>

            <!-- Setup Marker Info Window -->
            <div ui-map-info-window="myInfoWindow">
                <h1>Marker</h1>
            </div>
```

In JS

```
        $scope.showMarkerInfo = function(marker) {
            $scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        };
```

Comment: Fixed:  not actually fix, the reason is the latlng from async callback. So angularjs doesn't know. Use `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: Could you post your complete fix in code to help others?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, for those who look:

```
$scope.showMarkerInfo = function(marker) {
    $scope.$apply();
    $scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
};
```